# Mapping jpeg or bmp indoor map to use GraphHopper

Tags: android, navigation, indoor-positioning-system, graphhopper

I'm developing an application for the indoor navigation. I have image files of the various floors of the building in which to navigate (in pdf/jpeg/bmp...). I also have an Excel file with position (x,y) of vertices with related edges.
How i can map this image? there's something to draw a graph above the image? i'm searching possibily something compatible with GraphHopper (i'll use GraphHopper to generate shortest roads thanks to Dijkstra algorithms)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to import the data using a custom excel import functionality. E.g. have a look into the simpler [PrinctonReader](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/graphhopper/reader/PrinctonReader.java) or the [shapefile reader](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/pull/616) or the [unit tests](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/master/core/src/test/java/com/graphhopper/routing/AbstractRoutingAlgorithmTester.java#L114-L153) or [here](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/master/core/src/test/java/com/graphhopper/routing/AbstractRoutingAlgorithmTester.java#L480-L518).

I.e. something like this in Java:

```
GraphHopperStorage graph = createStorage...
graph.edge(0, 1, 2, true).setWayGeometry(Helper.createPointList(1.5, 1));
graph.edge(0, 2, 2, true);
```

Then you could try to load the image as leaflet map tile somehow replacing the default ones.